# What happens when we integrate angular displacement $θ$ (question picture given below)?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

Here I was trying to Solve this question and I thought what if we integrate both $\alpha$ (angular acceleration) and the value we get when we equate torque with Iα. If we do so We get the desired answer but its only possible if integrating $θ$ will give back $θ$ (angular displacement) which i dont know is possible or not and I also dont have any idea of what limits to put while integrating. please guide me here and help me solve this problem.

[image: Question number 7]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that

$\displaystyle \tau = I \frac {d \omega}{dt}$

where $I$ is the moment of inertia of the disc about its axis and $\omega = \frac {d \theta} {dt}$ is the disc's angular velocity.

So

$\displaystyle I \frac {d \omega}{dt} = a \theta + b$

But notice that

$\displaystyle \frac {d \omega}{dt} = \frac {d \omega} {d \theta} \frac {d \theta} {d t} = \omega \frac {d \omega} {d \theta}$

So we have

$\displaystyle I \omega \frac {d \omega} {d \theta} = a \theta + b
\\ \displaystyle \Rightarrow I \frac {\omega^2} 2 = a \frac {\theta^2} 2 + b \theta + c$

where $c$ is a constant of integration. Use the fact that $\omega=0$ when $\theta=0$ and you are done.